# I'm not getting the expected result of the variable I'm calling

Tags: javascript, variables

I came across something strange. Here two variables which store two differents results:

```
const membersSortedByCurrentStageTotalPoints = teamMembers.sort((a, b) => compareRanking(a,b,currentIndex));
      
const membersSortedByRankingType = teamMembers.sort((a, b) => compare(a, b, "points"))
```

But when I'm using the variable `membersSortedByCurrentStageTotalPoints` I get the results of the variable `membersSortedByRankingType`.

Anyone would know why ?

Comment: `.sort()` mutates the array in place and returns the same array. `membersSortedByCurrentStageTotalPoints` ***is*** `teamMembers`, not just a copy of it. Same with `membersSortedByRankingType`. You have three names for the same array.

Comment: Related: [Does .sort function change original array?](/q/24074968/4642212), [How can you sort an array without mutating the original array?](/q/9592740/4642212), [Why A and B are equal after sort()?](/q/26262318/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

From the [MDN documentation for `sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> Return value
>
> The sorted array. Note that the array is sorted in place, and no copy
> is made.

The two variables both have the same value: A reference to the same array.